# MASM calculator

Tags: assembly, masm

I wrote a simple calculator,
but my input form is
ex: input1:0101
    input2:1010
I don't know how to modify my code to satisfy the question below

http://codepad.org/gr1ypFwO

The program should then let the user input the Mathematic Form for calculations.
The operations of Mathematic Form are able to contain
1) adding
2) subtracting
3) multiplying
4) dividing

The operations of Mathematic Form are able to contain
1) binary,
2) octal,
3) decimal
4) hexadecimal

No bracket is considered, but the operations priorities must be in this program.
The program should then display the results in decimal.
For example: -11b + 22o * 33d / 0ah, 22o * -33d + 0bh / 111b

Comment: Sorry, but I'm having a hard time figuring out your question.

Comment: Questions should be as self-contained as possible. If you need to link to 400+ lines of code then you probably haven't spent enough time narrowing down the problem.